# Stop Console.app from auto-scrolling while I'm reading a log

Tags: console

When using Apple’s [Console.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_%28OS_X%29) to read logs, the window automatically scrolls to the bottom when a new entry is posted to the log. But I'm trying to read something in the middle of the log.

Is there some way to shutoff this *auto-scroll-to-bottom* feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does disabling the `Now` button in the bottom right of Console help? It should stop the log from scrolling with new updates.

[image: Console]

Comment: I had no idea that button was modal. Seems like an odd user-interface. When clicked so the "Now" button has a blue background the auto-scroll feature is "ON", grey background means "OFF". At least in Mountain Lion, Mac OS X 10.8.x. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, you got the idea! Glad to help.